# Code doesn't get excuted after using continue in while loop

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, continue, c89

I wrote the following code using a complier which was configured to be suitable with c89 standard using eclipse.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i=0;
    printf("initial value for variable i is: %d\n",i);
    while (i<3)
    {
        if (i==1) {continue;}
        printf("%d\n",i);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the code doesn't get excuted (No errors at all) and nothing shows in the console. When removing the following line of code `if (i==1) {continue;}` everything works correctly.

Comment: When `i` is `1`, it doesn't get its value changed, so it is still `1` on the next iteration, and the next, and … it takes a long time to change from `1`.  One advantage of a `for` loop is that it bundles the controls — you'd not see the problem with `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)` as the loop; the `continue` would jump to the `i++` in the loop control.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's right, can u publish it as an answer to accept it

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Just something strange happened when using continue inside while loop does the code continue to run without checking the condition?!

Comment: It checks the condition on each iteration, but the value in `i` stays at `1` because the `continue` skips over the `i++;` line.  So the condition never changes; the program doesn't stop.  That is probably why no output appears — you say you are using Eclipse as your IDE, and it's "terminals" appear to the programs as a non-terminal, so I/O is fully buffered and no output appears until the buffer fills, you call `fflush(stdout)`, or the program _does_ stop.

Answer (score 3):

When `i` is `1`, it doesn't get its value changed, so it is still `1` on the next iteration, and the next, and … it takes a long time to change from `1`.

One advantage of a `for` loop is that it bundles the loop controls in a single line. You'd not see the problem with `for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)` as the loop; the `continue` would jump to the `i++` in the loop control.

You say you are using Eclipse as your IDE.  That's probably why no output appears at all.  Its "terminals" appear to the programs as a non-terminal, so I/O is fully buffered (rather than line buffered as is normally the case with terminal output).  That in turn means that no output appears until the buffer fills, you call `fflush(stdout)`, or the program does stop.  It's a known issue with Eclipse.  You could call [`setvbuf()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.6): add a line `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBUF, BUFSIZ);` at the start to ensure line buffering is in effect.